# Could you get 16 Efficiency 1 books and combine them to make an Efficiency 5 book?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It takes

- 2 lvl 1 books to make a lvl 2 book.
- 2 lvl 2 to make lvl 3.
- 2 lvl 3 to make lvl 4.
- 2 lvl 4 to make lvl 5.

So... 1 lvl 5 book = 2 lvl 4 = 4 lvl 3 = 8 lvl 2 = 16 lvl 1 books.

Could you then continuously combine 16 lvl 1 books up to get a lvl 5 book?

Or does the cost penalty increase like it does when repairing weapons/tools/armour?

Would it become "Too Expensive" before you got there?

Comment: Haven't tested yet, but it should work. Combining more into it or the tool afterwards would rather be the problem. And that it costs a lot of XP. I'm pretty sure it's always cheaper to start with high/a lot of enchantments and not combine as often.

Comment: Not sure if I should vote to close this as a duplicate, but this question will likely help you for more understanding of enchantments: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254360/is-there-an-optimum-enchantment-strategy-in-minecraft?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I've tested this, and here are the results:

- Combining 16 Efficiency I books into 8 Efficiency II books: 2 levels each (16 levels)
- Combining these 8 books into 4 Efficiency III books: 5 levels each (20 levels)
- Combining these 4 books into 2 Efficiency IV books: 10 levels each (20 levels)
- Combining these 2 books into 1 Efficiency V book: 19 levels
- Applying this Efficiency V book onto an unenchanted diamond pickaxe: 20 levels

**Even with [prior work penalty](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil_mechanics#Prior_Work_penalty), the highest individual level cost does not go above 20, which means that it is not only possible, but also reasonably achievable in a survival game.** However, it costs a whopping 95 levels to fully enchant a tool using only Efficiency I books.

If you're dead set on using this method, combine the books as soon as you have the levels to do so. Since you level up a lot faster when you have low levels, it would take a *lot* less XP (and time) to combine books as you go than if you waited until you're level 95.