# What's the most efficient way of combining books and tools to reduce experience cost?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In **Java Edition** Minecraft, you can use an anvil to combine an enchanted book with a tool, granting it that enchantment. However, if you want to apply a **second** book, the cost will **increase**, and so on with more books. To **reduce** the effect of this cost increase, you can combine books **with** other books for a **smaller** experience cost, and when applied to the tool, it will only cost the amount that **one** book would.

The question is, then, what's the **most efficient** way of combining books with tools to **minimize** experience cost?

Comment: What sort of tools do you want? It makes a difference on whether you want silk touch or not, unbreaking or not, bane of Arthropods or not,...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an optimum enchantment strategy in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254360/is-there-an-optimum-enchantment-strategy-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gnembon covers the problem in his video:

Summarizing his findings, there are three main factors

- level of the enchantment (Fortune III will be three times as expensive as Fortune I); if a book or tool has multiple ones, that's just a sum.
- rarity of the enchantment - a multipler of the level; Efficiency counts as 1x, Fortune - 2x, so applying Efficiency IV will cost as much as Fortune II
- base cost - an extra cost added with every operation, doubles with every subsequent one.

That last part is the most prohibitive, meaning applying enchantments to a tool one after another will quickly drive the cost way up. The way to approach it is to combine enchantments in form of a binary tree - merge same cost books in pairs (then potentially merge these pairs), treating the original tool as one of the 'leaves' of the binary tree (same as one level 1 book).

[image]

When combining books swap their positions in the anvil and always choose the cheaper option, and prefer to merge items of similar cost.

Comment: Apex Diamond Pickaxe. Who needs Netherite?

Comment: @Cyphase IIRC, diamond is slightly cheaper to enchant, so first enchant, then upgrade with Netherite.

Comment: @SF. "prefer to merge items of similar cost" why is that in particular?

Comment: @Slav: because the cost of application after merging will be proportional to cost of the more expensive of the two items. Combining 4 cheap together and merging them all with 1 expensive will result in much lower end price than merging each (or even some) of the 4 into the expensive one separately.