# What is the minimal-cost enchanting order with books for the various armor pieces/tools/weapons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I looked at [this previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254360/100233) and while it gives the general idea, the answers do not provide the exact strategy.

I am looking for something like this (found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil_mechanics#Planning_the_enchanting_order)):

[image]

This is the optimal enchanting order for a pair of boots. What is the optimal one for the other armor pieces and the various weapons and tools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most efficient way of combining books and tools to reduce experience cost?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380918/whats-the-most-efficient-way-of-combining-books-and-tools-to-reduce-experience) Unless the question is explicitly, finding the exact best combination for each armour piece?

Comment: @corsaka the question is to find explicitly the best combination/sequence, yes. should I rephrase the question? I thought it was clear.